# How to format my book before sending it to a publisher?

Tags: formatting, book, publisher

I am looking to send a copy of a horror anthology that i finished recently to a publisher and don't know what the editing format of the pdf should be or how the letter to the publisher should go.

Need help.

Comment: Check if the publisher has guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

There are myriad of publishers out there, and each of them has their own rules. Some require a Word document with your name and contact information in the header of every page, page numbers in the footer, and section titles formatted. Others want none of that and only that the document is in Times New Roman, double-spaced, and left-justified. Then there are those who only accept plain-text, ASCII files. There is a handful who accept formatted, print-ready PDFs.

Like Michael suggested, carefully read the submission guidelines page on your publisher's web site. You may find out many interesting facts, like that they do not accept new manuscripts at all, or they only want novellas shorter than 40k words, or only short stories, etc.